# How to use Twitter API pagination for getting user tweets

Tags: php, json, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am fetching tweets of a user. I need to show all tweets with ajax pagination. How can I achieve that?

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json

**Tried**

I am using the above link. I heard about `max_id`, `since_id` but do not know how to use that. I have tried with `max_id` and `since_id`, then the collection is repeating. I am not getting any cursor response.

**my code**

```
$api_key = urlencode('*********'); // Consumer Key (API Key)
$api_secret = urlencode('***********'); // Consumer Secret (API Secret)
$auth_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token';

    // what we want?
    $data_username = '********'; // username
    $data_count = 1; // number of tweets
    $data_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json';

    // get api access token
    $api_credentials = base64_encode($api_key . ':' . $api_secret);

    $auth_headers = 'Authorization: Basic ' . $api_credentials . "\r\n" .
            'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";

    $auth_context = stream_context_create(
            array(
                'http' => array(
                    'header' => $auth_headers,
                    'method' => 'POST',
                    'content' => http_build_query(array('grant_type' => 'client_credentials',)),
                )
            )
    );

    $auth_response = json_decode(file_get_contents($auth_url, 0, $auth_context), true);
    $auth_token = $auth_response['access_token'];

    // get tweets
    $data_context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header' => 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $auth_token . "\r\n",)));

    $datas = json_decode(file_get_contents($data_url . '?include_rts=true&count=' . $data_count . '&screen_name=' . urlencode($data_username), 0, $data_context), true);

    // result - do what you want
    print('<pre>');
    print_r($datas);
```

**Question**

What values i have to pass for getting pagination url?

Thank you.

Comment: Please post your example code.

Comment: any body knows the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The Twitter API response should include a `next_token` variable which can be used for subsequent API calls / Pagination.

See https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/pagination for more information on the topic (this refers to v2, as v1.1 is deprecated by now)